# Spring MVC, RESTful Services & Apache Shiro Strategy

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, shiro

I am busy working on a project that needs a REST API to allow users to access their information on a server. I have the system working using Spring MVC and the `MappingJacksonJsonView` to return JSON where needed.

I now want to include security in the system to firstly, ensure users authenticate themselves and have the correct permissions to access a resource and secondly I want to have enough fine-grained control of the data to make sure that a user can only access publicly available portions of a resource or if they have the correct permissions the entire resource.

So for example:

**Scenario A:** User A wants to access their list of messages, as well as their name and phone number. They would then get authenticated and their permissions would allow them to access all of their own information.

**Scenario B:** User A wants to access User B's phone number - therefore excluding User B's list of messages in the response as A doesn't have permissions to access that portion of info.

- **Q1:** Is there a neat way of going
  about doing this using Apache Shiro
  and Spring MVC?
- **Q2:** Does anybody
  have an example or link to a tutorial
  on how somebody else has achieved
  this?
- **Q3:** What sort of permissions
  scheme, using Shiro, would be most
  efficient to allow this type of fine
  grained control?

I haven't worked with Shiro before, but from playing with examples and reading the documentation it looks like this is possible and that Shiro would be the best fit for the solution. I am open to other solutions though.

**Edit:** One solution, and I have no idea if this is possible with Shiro & Jackson, is to annotate properties in my POJO's that I can mark as public or private. Or even better, mark them with the permission necessary to access them. Then when Jackson prints out the JSON representation of the object it can inspect the permissions for the current property and decide whether to print the property or not from its annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple for this problem. I created a set of view classes for Jackson:

```
public class SecureViews {
    public static class Public{};
    public static class Authenticated extends Public{};
    public static class User extends Authenticated{};
    public static class Internal extends User {};
}
```

I then annotated all the getter methods for each entity I want to be secured by adding the following:

```
@JsonView(SecureViews.Authenticated.class)
public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}
```

What the above rule means is that only users who are authenticated within the system my view a user's phone number.

Or

```
@JsonView(SecureViews.User.class)
public List<Event> getEvents() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(events);
}
```

I then created an interface and implemented that interface in all my secure entities:

```
public interface SecurePropertyInterface {
    Class<?> getMaxPermissionLevel(Long userID);
}
```

And here is the implementation of that method:

```
public Class<?> getMaxPermissionLevel(Long userID) {
        if (userID != null && userID == uid) {
            return SecureViews.User.class;
        }
        if (SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated()) {
            return SecureViews.Authenticated.class;
        }

        return SecureViews.Public.class;
    }
```

Now for the magic. Extend `MappingJacksonJsonView` and override the following method:

```
@Override
protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        Long userID = CTConversionUtils.convertToLong(request.getParameter("id"));
        model = (Map<String, Object>) super.filterModel(model);

        Class<?> viewClass = SecureViews.Public.class;

        if(SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated()) {
            viewClass = SecureViews.Authenticated.class;
        }

        for (Entry<String, Object> modelEntry : model.entrySet()) {
            if (modelEntry.getValue() instanceof SecurePropertyInterface) {
                viewClass = ((SecurePropertyInterface)modelEntry.getValue()).getMaxPermissionLevel(userID);
            }
        }
        objectMapper.viewWriter(viewClass).writeValue(getJsonGenerator(response), model);
    }
```

You can also override the `setObjectMapper` method to capture the objectMapper when Spring sets up your `MappingJacksonJsonView` .

My Spring config looks like this:

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver"
        p:order="1">
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="json" value="*/*" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="com.bytesizecreations.connecttext.json.SecureMappingJacksonJsonView">
                    <property name="objectMapper">
                        <bean
                            class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

So what do we have here now? Every time a response needs to be deserialized to JSON the renderedMergedOutputModel method is called. If the user's id is in the request we store that. We can then loop through the model map and check if each value is a SecurePropertyInterface and if it is get its max permission level.

This strategy seems to serve my purposes properly. When users request a list of users then they get only the authenticated properties, but when users request their own details they get only their private properties.

I suspect this code can be improved further though, but I have spent way too much time trying to make it less complicated.

Comment: You can do `Class<?>` and do away with the raw type warnings.